# How to arrange six authors in two lines in an article

Tags: author

I'm coauthor of an article with five other authors, I want to arrange three authors in first line and another three authors in second line, but `\and` just show two authors in line.

In other words I want to arrange this part in two lines **NOT** three.

```
\author{%
 A\thanks{1}
 \and
 B\thanks{2}
 \and
 C\thanks{3}
 \and
 D\thanks{4}
 \and
 E\thanks{5}
 \and
 F\thanks{6}
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and/or provide a minimal working example of your document? Otherwise people cannot actually help you, because we do not know what is going on in your document. (If you are using a non-standard documentclass, such as a journal template, make sure to also add a link to the template).

Comment: So, can you confirm that you are working with a standard or KOMA class such as `article` or `scrartcl` and you are using `\maketitle` to generate this entry? If I add your code snippet into a minimal document these authors will appear in one line (because they are single letters). Is that all correct?

Comment: Definitely you can't get clear suggestion unless otherwise you mentioned your class file name, better to provide the `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the lack of information, I would suggest, you not use `\and` and simply replace it with commas. That way you can add a custom `\\` whereever you need it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\title{Example title}
\author{%
    A\thanks{1},
    B\thanks{2},
    C\thanks{3},\\
    D\thanks{4},
    E\thanks{5},
    F\thanks{6}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

However, if this has the desired effect depends on the length of the author names as well as your margins, none of which were specified. I also wonder, why you chose to use `\maketitle` in the first place. It typically causes a lot of layout-issues people tend to avoid.